# npm run tauri devでGUIアプリが起動しない。(WSL2・ubuntu)

Tags: rust, wsl

#### 解決したい点

Tauriの公式セットアップ方法に則り、
WSL2(ubuntu22.04) => cargo create-tauri-appでnpm・react・tsでアプリを作成した後、npm i + npm run tauri devでアプリを実行すると、下記の表示が出るのみで、GUIアプリが起動しません。(yarnなどでも同じ症状)
x11アプリ(xeyes)などは正常に動作するので、VcXsrv(-nowgl付き)は正常に作動していると思われます。
解決策をご教授いただけると幸いです。

```
npm run tauri dev --verbose

 「アプリ名」@0.0.0 tauri
 tauri dev
     Running BeforeDevCommand (`npm run dev`)
 xmas-countdown-app@0.0.0 dev
 vite

  VITE v4.4.11  ready in 161 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:1420/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
        Info Watching /「パス」/ for changes...
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.09s

npm verb exit 0
npm info ok
```

#### 試したこと

1. 実行ポート変更(devPath ＆ vite.config.ts)
2. ログファイルの確認
3. Xserverの6000番ポート開放
4. ファイアウォール設定
5. DISPLAY環境変数の設定
6. package-lock.json・node_modulesを削除しnpm installの再度実行

**開発環境**
Windows 10 Home
windows・WebView2
WSL2・Ubuntu 22.04
npm@9.8.1
node@v18.18.2
Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Build Tools

**npm run tauri info 実行結果**

```
[✔] Environment
    - OS: Ubuntu 22.04 X64
    ✔ webkit2gtk-4.0: 2.42.1
    ✔ rsvg2: 2.52.5
    ✔ rustc: 1.73.0 (2023-10-03)
    ✔ Cargo: 1.73.0 (2023-08-26)
    ✔ rustup: 1.26.0 (2023-04-05)
    ✔ Rust toolchain: stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
    - node: 18.18.2
    - yarn: 1.22.19
    - npm: 9.8.1

[-] Packages
    - tauri [RUST]: 1.5.2
    - tauri-build [RUST]: 1.5.0
    - wry [RUST]: 0.24.4
    - tao [RUST]: 0.16.4
    - tauri-cli [RUST]: 1.5.3
    - @tauri-apps/api [NPM]: 1.5.0
    - @tauri-apps/cli [NPM]: 1.5.2

[-] App
    - build-type: bundle
    - CSP: unset
    - distDir: ../dist
    - devPath: http://localhost:1420/
    - framework: React
    - bundler: Vite
```

**インストール済みパッケージ**

```
sudo apt install 
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    wget \
    file \
    libssl-dev \
    libgtk-3-dev \
    libayatana-appindicator3-dev \
    librsvg2-dev
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "「アプリ名」",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "tauri": "tauri"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "@tauri-apps/api": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.4",
    "@tauri-apps/cli": "^1.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: これ。もしかしてポートフォワーディングなしで
http://localhost:1420 にアクセスしたりしてません？
localhostは通常ホストOS=WindowsのループバックになってるのでWSLに通信するためにはポートフォワーディングの設定が必要だと思ったのですが、やっていますか？

wslからcurl http://localost:1420 --verbose　してみて何が帰ってくるのか観察。wslでOKでwindowsからいけないのであればフォワーディング設定を考えてください。

Comment: ポートフォワーディングは設定していないです。
恐縮ですが、ポートフォワーディングをするにあたって参考になるサイト等を教えてもらえると助かります。

Comment: https://gunmagisgeek.com/blog/other/7171 などいかがでしょう。

Comment: 何度も申し訳ありません。
記事通りにポートフォワーディングをして、外部機器などからも接続が可能になったのですが、npm run devを実行した際の"webサイト"のみにしか接続ができず、npm run tauri devを実行しても、"tauriGUIアプリ"は起動しません。
下記はnpm run tauri dev --verboseの実行結果です。